# shooting moving location in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working in a game for my college and i stuck in one thing.

when i try to shoot with my hero the bullet go's up only or side i need my bullet go's where ever my hero rotate plz help me this is my code

```
func spownBullet() {
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bullet")
    let hero = self.childNodeWithName("hero") as! SKSpriteNode
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    bullet.position = CGPointMake(hero.position.x, hero.position.y)
    bullet.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 30)
    let bulletact = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 300, duration: 1)
    bullet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(bulletact))
    self.addChild(bullet)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want your bullet to go a certain distance (e.g. 300) in the same angle as your "hero" sprite is rotated.

Here's a function to compute the destination point:

```
 // destination point moving at angle
 // ---------------------------------
 func endPointMovingSpriteFrom(origin:CGPoint, atAngle angle:CGFloat,forDistance distance:CGFloat ) -> CGPoint
 {
   let deltaX = distance / sin(angle + CGFloat(M_PI)/2)
   let deltaY = distance / cos(angle + CGFloat(M_PI)/2)
   return CGPoint(x: origin.x - deltaX, y:origin.y - deltaY)
 }
```

You can use it to compute the destination and then use the destination in a moveTo action:

```
 let bulletDestination = endPointMovingSpriteFrom(hero.position, atAngle:hero.zRotation, forDistance:300)
 let bulletact = SKAction.moveTo(bulletDestination, duration: 1)
```

Comment: The function can be global.  The two lines using it should simply replace the one you have in your example code (where you create bulletact).

Comment: ty but i have where should i but the second code (  let bulletDestination = endPointMovingSpriteFrom(hero.position, atAngle:hero.rotation, forDistance:300)
 let bulletact = SKAction.moveTo(bulletDestination, duration: 1) ) in touchesMoved ..?

Comment: Where to trigger the bullet spawn depends on the rest of your program structure and on the requirements/rules of your game.  You should make that a separate question and provide related code.